# Java conventions for field name as keyword

Tags: java, conventions

Is there any convention for fields with name same as java keyword?
For example want to create field with name "public":

```
public class Event{
   private boolean public_;
}
```

Comment: There is no generally accepted convention for this. Use whatever convention makes sense for your project. I would prefer `isPublic` instead of `public_` but that's purely personal preference.

Comment: i would give it meaningfulName like `isPublic`

Comment: I have a convention for myself - avoid them. Find a synonym and use that...

Comment: @SMA and what would be the name of the getter method, `isIsPublic()`, or `getIsPublic()`?

Comment: depends on convention you then follow i.e. javabeans for e.g. @ppeterka

Comment: @ppeterka Just `isPublic()`. Having a member variable and a method with the same name is not a problem.

Comment: @Jasper try telling that to 3rd party libraries that try to find the getter methods using crude string jumbling and reflection...

Comment: @ppeterka if a 3rd party library does that then it is buggy and you should file a bug report...

Comment: @Jesper I'm afraid I have to disagree. This is defined in the [JavaBeans naming convention](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf), section 8.3.2: `In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a getter method to match the pattern: public boolean is<PropertyName>();
This “is<PropertyName>” method may be provided instead of a “get<PropertyName>” method, or it may be provided in addition to a “get<PropertyName>” method.`

Comment: @ppeterka that's the Javabean specification, not Java in general. Reasonable if the library is designed to work with Javabeans, not reasonable otherwise.

Comment: @AndyTurner anyone is free to shoot themselves in the foot as much as they like - as long as not on my project. I don't see any arguments against following the JavaBeans naming convention, and see very low efforts accompanied by tremendous gains in following it - I do also maintain code, and not having to deal with things a thousand ways helps a lot. So this is why I am against promoting too much freedom *in this case*.

Comment: @ppeterka Note that the JavaBeans specification does not require that the name of the private member variable is the same as the name used in the getter and setter methods. In fact, the presence and name of the getter/setter methods defines the property (see section 8.3.1). What the name of the underlying member variable is, doesn't matter for the JavaBeans API. So you can name the variable `isPublic`, or `public_`, or whatever you like, as long as you have `isPublic()` / `setPublic(boolean)` methods it's still a valid JavaBean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard convention since the [code convention document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) released by sun in 1999.

The only reference to variable names on that document is the following (chapter 9):

> Except for variables, all instance, class, and
>   class constants are in mixed case with a lowercase
>   first letter. Internal words start with capital
>   letters.
>   Variable names should be short yet meaningful.
>   The choice of a variable name should be
>   mnemonic— that is, designed to indicate to the
>   casual observer the intent of its use. One-character
>   variable names should be avoided except
>   for temporary “throwaway” variables. Common
>   names for temporary variables are i, j, k,
>   m, and n for integers; c, d, and e for characters.

As you can see there is no reference to how to use a keyword as variable name. The only tip that I can suggest are:

- avoid it and use a different word (a synonym)
- if you choose to use a keyword, be coherent and use the same convention for the whole code (for example prefix it with _ or suffix it with the name of the class)

Comment: Also, if you only care about API response, you probably can use @JsonProperty annotation above your getter.

Answer (score 5):

The general convention (nothing official, but for experience) in this cases is to add the name of the class as a suffix.

`private boolean publicEvent`

Comment: thanks for tip. I will use that.

Answer (score 0):

To shorten the name consider combining first letter of class with keyword, in your case:

```
ePublic
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think that is official convention, but thanks for tip

Comment: But there's no standard convention, it's just my one way of dealing with java keywords. The other is to just avoid it.